# How to display context-sensitive help for buttons?

Tags: buttons, context-sensitive-help

I have several buttons in my application that require some explanation (1-3 SHORT  sentences). Something like context sensitive help.

what is the best way to provide the user this explanation?

- Tooltip? (annoying and "hidden")
- coach marks upon load?
- something else?

Comment: If really required, certainly not tooltip.

Comment: Can we see a screenshot so that we understand the context?

Comment: Is your application web? Mobile? Desktop?
Will the buttons always need explanation or could they be explained in a tutorial?

Comment: This is a Web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strenuously avoid coach marks and tutorials. They're mostly not effective; people tend to dismiss them right away and they don't want to read a manual to get started (http://www.nngroup.com/articles/mobile-instructional-overlay/). We've personally seen tutorial walkthroughs mostly fail in usability; most people seem to prefer trying to figure out what's going on and then getting help if they need it.

I don't see a problem with helper tips under the form field row, or with help bubbles (for tapping or clicking / hovering) for users who need it. However, if the buttons represent functionality that's complex enough that they need a couple of sentences, you might want to restructure the interface to use different elements that afford more explanation.

For example: Are these toolbar-type buttons that the user will interact with many times? Or are they part of a workflow or occasional / rare use system?

If these options are part of a one-time or occasional process, instead of making them buttons you might consider making each choice a radio with a single confirmation button. The confirmation text will ideally reflect the selected option. The default option should be the most popular, least-destructive, and/or most-recoverable option. (This example is in my head after using Zendesk earlier today to deal with an account of a former employee.)

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f81jgA.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

If the actions are going to be used somewhat frequently, but not enough for the user to really learn them, a fancy dropdown with explanatory text is helpful.

For example, in calendaring, most calendar servers understand an event marking you as busy (like a meeting) or available (like you have a reminder on your calendar to take medicine but you don't want it to block out meeting requests.) Here's how we explain this to users at Magneto:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. The buttons are not one time process and they are not part of a form. The user operates the application (web application)using these buttons. I'm sorry but  I can't share a screen, but imagine that I have a game with some buttons that are used by the player to operate the gave. most buttons are simple and intuitive. there are several buttons that requires some extra explanation.

Comment: In that case, I'd use a persistent help icon [?] near each / both buttons that triggers in-context help (i.e. a popover or tooltip). I wouldn't do a hover over the button itself; if these are repeated-use in-app tools, then potentially triggering a hover whenever you use the button gets annoying. Having a question-mark icon near the button(s) lets the user trigger help for more info but doesn't get in the way of someone who has learned them already.